# ASP.NET MVC link to another object same type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a set of questions. Each question has a link to another (next question). How can i correctly realize this in model? I think the variant

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TestAlibra.Models
{
    public class Question
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public int NextQuestion { get; set; }
    }
}
```

will be wrong, because this does not match EF criteria.
Also variant like

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TestAlibra.Models
{
    public class Question
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public int QuestionID { get; set; }

        public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
    }
}
```

looks very strange; I think it is also wrong.

Thanks for help!

Comment: is it like a tree of questions? you'll need to have a FK constraint to the same table. which you can do, but EF doesn't handle it well.

Comment: Yes, a tree of questions. But each question can have a link to only one another question.
Also I think about creating table with fields: questionID, nextQuestionID. Just for navigation. But I am not sure this is good idea to create table just for this.

Comment: yeah so your table will be like your first object, where NextQuestionId has a FK of Question.Id EF hates that because it will have to load a potentially infinite list of objects. Plus you'll want NextQuesionId to be nullable, again EF will complain.

Comment: I think your first object was correct. stick with that. load all the questions by 'questionarieId' and use linq to get the next question from your list of questions instead of having a complex object

Comment: dont even think of trying to serialize it to JSON

Comment: What's wrong with the second example? It looks just right, I might be overlooking something... oh wait... I think you just have to declare QuestionID as `int?`

Comment: @BrunoLM, I don't know, what is wrong with the second example. It just looks strange for me, because I am newbie in asp.net (started to learn it 1 month ago) and I am not sure it is normal practice to write such code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
public class Question
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int? QuestionID { get; set; }

    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

By naming convention `QuestionID` will be turned into a foreign key.

Note that I changed it to `int?`, that is because you need the foreign key to be nullable otherwise it would be impossible to insert into a table that requires a link to itself (how would you insert the first element?).

This class is exactly what database-first would automatically generate for you if you chose to generate classes from database.